# ListView imprime apenas o primeiro elemento do ArrayList

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, java-8

Meu aplicativo possui uma tela que lista todos os elementos cadastrados no BD. O método que utilizo pra listar os resultados retorna um List (na classe DiagnosticoDataSource), até aí tudo certo, o problema começa quando eu vou carregar a lista para exibir os resultados, ela exibe apenas o primeiro item (das checkbox selecionadas) e o algoritmo não permite inserir outro item após a primeira inserção.

Já procurei diversos modos de resolver este problema, inclusive achei uma questão bem parecida no forum, mas também não resolveu meu problema [Apenas imprime o primeiro elemento do ArrayList](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186763/apenas-imprime-o-primeiro-elemento-do-arraylist)

#### **Trechos de código**

**Diagnostico (tela que imprime no ListView):**

```
public void carregarLista() {
    DiagnosticoDataSource dsDiagnostico = new DiagnosticoDataSource(this);
    dsDiagnostico.open();
    List<DiagnosticoSintomas> diagnosticos = dsDiagnostico.getAlldiagnostico();
    dsDiagnostico.close();
    ArrayAdapter<DiagnosticoSintomas> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<DiagnosticoSintomas>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, diagnosticos);
    listDiagnostico.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**DiagnosticoDataSource:**

```
public class DiagnosticoDataSource {

private SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase;
private Database database;

private String[] colunas = { Database.COLUMN_ID, Database.COLUMN_SINTOMAS };

public DiagnosticoDataSource(Context context) {
    database = new Database(context);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    sqlDatabase = database.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    database.close();
}

public DiagnosticoSintomas create(DiagnosticoSintomas diagnosticoSintomas) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Database.COLUMN_ID, diagnosticoSintomas.get_id());
    values.put(Database.COLUMN_SINTOMAS, diagnosticoSintomas.getSintomas().toString());

    long id = 0;

    if (diagnosticoSintomas.get_id() != 0) {
        id = sqlDatabase.update(Database.TABLE_SINTOMAS, values, Database.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(diagnosticoSintomas.get_id()) });
    } else {
        id = sqlDatabase.insert(Database.TABLE_SINTOMAS, null, values);
    }

    return getDiagnostico((int) id);
}

public DiagnosticoSintomas getDiagnostico(int _id) {
    Cursor cursor = sqlDatabase.query(Database.TABLE_SINTOMAS,
            colunas, Database.COLUMN_ID + " = " + _id, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    DiagnosticoSintomas newDiagnostico = cursorToDiagnostico(cursor);

    cursor.close();

    return newDiagnostico;
}

public void delete(DiagnosticoSintomas diagnostico) {
    long id = diagnostico.get_id();
    sqlDatabase.delete(Database.TABLE_SINTOMAS, Database.COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
}

public List<DiagnosticoSintomas> getAlldiagnostico() {
    List<DiagnosticoSintomas> diagnosticos = new ArrayList<DiagnosticoSintomas>();

    Cursor cursor = sqlDatabase.query(Database.TABLE_SINTOMAS, colunas, null, null, null, null,
            Database.COLUMN_SINTOMAS);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        DiagnosticoSintomas diagnostico = cursorToDiagnostico(cursor);
        diagnosticos.add(diagnostico);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return diagnosticos;
}

private DiagnosticoSintomas cursorToDiagnostico(Cursor cursor) {
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    a.add(cursor.getString(1));
    DiagnosticoSintomas diagnostico = new DiagnosticoSintomas();
    diagnostico.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getLong(0) + ""));
    diagnostico.setSintomas(a);
    return diagnostico;
}

}
```

**Xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/diagnosticos"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
```

**Database:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE sintomas (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, sintomas TEXT);");

}
```

A resposta da questão do link diz que o problema é que o TextView apenas é preenchido quando a `convertView/v`é nula. A variável equivalente no meu código é `diagnosticoSintomas.get_id()` que está fazendo a mesma coisa, só que está verificando também quando a variável for diferente de 0. Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

O problema está no `values.put(Database.COLUMN_ID, diagnosticoSintomas.get_id());` da classe DiagnosticoDataSource, ele não tá recebendo um valor de id, ocasionando o erro apresentado. A solução do problema é:

Adicionar AUTOINCREMENT na coluna id da tabela sintomas na classe Database e remover a linha `values.put(Database.COLUMN_ID, diagnosticoSintomas.get_id());` já que não é mais necessário inserir um valor para o id.

**Database**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE sintomas (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, sintomas TEXT);");

}
```

**DiagnosticoDataSource**

```
public DiagnosticoSintomas create(DiagnosticoSintomas diagnosticoSintomas) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Database.COLUMN_SINTOMAS, diagnosticoSintomas.getSintomas().toString());

    long id = 0;

    if (diagnosticoSintomas.get_id() != 0) {
        id = sqlDatabase.update(Database.TABLE_SINTOMAS, values, Database.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(diagnosticoSintomas.get_id()) });
    } else {
        id = sqlDatabase.insert(Database.TABLE_SINTOMAS, null, values);
    }

    return getDiagnostico((int) id);
}
```